# How to pull only specific OU user data using Admin SDK

Tags: google-apps-script

How to pull only specific OU user data using Admin SDK

i tried with  query: 'orgUnitPath=/Gsuite POC Users', but it generate all users info

Below is my Sample Code

```js
  do {
    page = AdminReports.UserUsageReport.get('all', date, {
      query: 'orgUnitPath=/Gsuite POC Users',
      parameters: parameters.join(','),
      maxResults: 500,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the official [documentation for the endpoint](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/userUsageReport/get) you are using, there is an actual parameter to filter the results for OrgUnit.

> `orgUnitID`   **string**  ID of the organizational unit to report on. User activity will be shown only for users who belong to the specified organizational unit.

It will be as easy as to include this parameter:

```
do {
    page = AdminReports.UserUsageReport.get('all', date, {
      orgUnitId= <<your org ID here>>,
      parameters: parameters.join(','),
      maxResults: 500,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
```

You can retrieve the organization units ID of all your units [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits/list) or directly with the [get endpoint](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits/get) if you already know the path.